# How to add a custom tab to the new Azure DevOps Releases Hub with an extension?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

The Azure DevOps UI is evolving, and I'm trying to add a custom tab to the new **Release Pipeline** view while looking at a particular release:

[image: New UI]

I was able to do so in the old UI, using the `ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-summary-tab` **contribution** and targeting `ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-details-view`:

```
{
  "id": "my-release-tab",
  "type": "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-summary-tab",
  "description": "My release tab",
  "targets": ["ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-details-view"],
  "properties": {
    "name": "My Custom Tab",
    "uri": "tab.html"
  },
  "includes": ["ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-service-data-external"]
}
```

[image: Old UI with custom tab]

What is the new contribution type? Has the target changed?

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/preview/new-release-summary?view=vsts) it looks like you need to change the contribution type and target to this:

```
{ 
   "id": "rm-details-view-sample", 
   "type": "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-summary-section", 
   "targets": [ "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-details-summary-tab" ], 
   "properties": { 
      "name": "Tab name", 
      "uri": "index.html" 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Shayki Abramczyk adds custom section, not tab. If you want to add custom tab to the release detail you should use configuration like this:

```json
{
    "id": "rm-details-view-sample",
    "type": "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-summary-tab",
    "targets": [
        "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-details-view"
    ],
    "properties": { 
        "name": "Tab name", 
        "uri": "index.html" 
    }
}
```