# How to add a new tab in pull requests in Azure-Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pull-request

In below image I can see that there are multiple tabs when we create pull request like Overview, Files, Update, Commits, etc. I want to add a new tab in pull request. I tried searching on internet but was not able to find much. It will be great if someone can help me with it.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: i dont think thats possible without creating a full blown extension\addon?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I am ok with adding addon\extension. I am just not sure what to search in google to learn more about it. I actually want to know some document references that can be useful in this scenario. I don't know the term I should use to search for it. I tried tabs, options, extensions, addons, etc but it didn't work.

Comment: sorry, that I dont know as well, but I'm 99% sure that there are no settings you can tweak to do that.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I don't need a quick setting. I am fine with full-blown extension development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @4c74356b41 AFAIK that's not possible without creating a full-blown extension\addon.

Reference taken from :
[Azure DevOps-Add extension that adds custom tab to Pipeline / Release Definition page (not the summary page) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003204/azure-devops-add-extension-that-adds-custom-tab-to-pipeline-release-definition)

```
. I don't know the term I should use to search for it.I am just not sure what to search in google to learn more about it.
```

you can search for the following terms on Google :

- Azure DevOps extension samples
- Azure DevOps extension custom tab
- Azure Devops Extensions Overview

```
  I am ok with adding addon\extension.  I actually want to know some document references that can be useful in this scenario
```

As you are ok with extension you can refer this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/overview?view=azure-devops) Extensions overview.

To create a new tab in a pull request, you need to create an extension that adds the new functionality to Azure DevOps. You can use Visual Studio to create a new Azure DevOps extension project.

Reference for Working with [Pull Requests](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/pullrequests/) in Visual Studio Code and Azure DevOps

Reference [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127756/how-to-add-a-custom-tab-to-the-new-azure-devops-releases-hub-with-an-extension) thread

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go through them :)